# Found 4 elements with non-unique id while using multiple select2 in one form

Tags: php, jquery, html

In my form i'm using select2 based on roles there are 5 role so i'm taking loop of facilities to show select2....i'm getting following error in my code:

> [DOM] Found 4 elements with non-unique id

select2 libraries

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

my html $facilities contain list of facilities coming from database

```
<select class="form-control required select2fc" name="facility[]" id="fcss" multiple="multiple" style="width:60%;" required="true" >
     <?php                 
        for ($i=0; $i < count($facilities); $i++) { ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $facilities[$i]['id'];?>"><?php echo $facilities[$i]['Name'];?></option>  
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

my script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".select2fc").select2();
});
```

Comment: `id` attributes need to be unique. That's what that message says. Don't use the same `id` (`id="fcss"`?) for your selects.

Comment: ok..now i have taken diffferent id's i.e id="fcss`+index+`" now error not showing but select2 not working

Comment: Which is strange since you're triggering `select2` via class `.select2fc` and not via `id`. Use your browsers console to find out what might have gone wrong. Also note [the troubleshooting page](https://select2.org/troubleshooting/common-problems) for select2.